# Calling a native callback from managed .NET code (when loading the managed code using COM)

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

I am really confused by the multitude of misinformation about native / managed interop.

I have a regular C++ exe which is NOT built using CLR stuff (it is neither Managed C++ nor C++/CLI and never will be). This C++ exe is "in charge", there is no managed wrapper for it.

I would like to access some code I have in a C# assembly from my C++ exe. I can access the C# assembly from my C++ code using COM. However, when my C# code detects an event I would like it to call back into my C++ code. The C++ function pointer to call back into will be provided at runtime. Note that the C++ function pointer is to a function found in the exe's execution environment. It may use static members from there. I don't want the managed code to try and load up some DLL to call a function (there is no DLL).

How do I pass this C++ function pointer to my C# code through COM/.NET and have my C# code successfully call it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer?view=net-6.0):

1. Create a delegate type that matches the signature of the native function, keeping in mind the right way to marshal types and using [`MarshalAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute?view=net-6.0) as needed
2. Communicate the native function pointer from your native code to your C# code however you can (in your case, it looks like you can use your COM -> C# connection)
3. Use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` to turn the pointer into a C#-callable delegate
4. Invoke the delegate with your parameters

Junfeng Zhang has an example of doing this [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301160426/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/14/181932.aspx).

Note the restrictions mentioned on MSDN:

> The GetDelegateForFunctionPointer
> method has the following restrictions:
>
> - Generics are not supported in interop
>   scenarios.
> - You cannot pass an invalid function
>   pointer to this method.
> - You can use this method only for pure
>   unmanaged function pointers.
> - You cannot use this method with
>   function pointers obtained through C++
>   or from the GetFunctionPointer method.
> - You cannot use this method to create a
>   delegate from a function pointer to
>   another managed delegate.

The part about C++ is likely referring to function pointers for class methods.  This should still work for global functions.

Comment: In step 2 will the function pointer initially arrive in C#-land as an IntPtr?

Comment: To get the pointer from C/C++ to C#, it will be marshaled.  Yes, C/C++ pointers are represented as a C# `IntPtr` whose size is platform-specific.

Comment: I'm probably doing something dumb. The C++ compiler complains that it can't convert my parameter from voic(__cdecl*)(UINT) to long (the method takes an IntPtr in C#). Also, Zhang's example involves a C++ function pointer retrieved in C# not one retrieved from C++...

Comment: I casted my function pointer to a long in C++ and while the compiler complained that the type cast involved "pointer truncation", it seemed to work?

Comment: The pointer truncation warning could be an issue if you move to a 64-bit platform.  If you have to cast a pointer, use `UINT_PTR`.  For more info: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=431298

Comment: If I use UINT_PTR then I get a regular "possible lost of data" warning :D

Answer (score 4):

The standard COM approach is to subscribe to an event that's raised by the COM server.  Use can use the event keyword in C#, CLR interop automatically implements the COM glue that's needed.  Use the IConnectionPoint interface in your C++ code.  Backgrounder [is here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/connectionpoint.aspx).